# call a function in success of datatable ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

Is that possible to invoke a javascript function in success of datatable ajax call.
Here is the code am trying to use,

```
var oTable = $('#app-config').dataTable(
            {
                "bAutoWidth": false,                                                
                "bDestroy":true,
                "bProcessing" : true,
                "bServerSide" : true,
                "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
                "sAjaxSource" : url,                    
                "fnServerData" : function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
                    alert("sSource"+ sSource);
                    alert("aoData"+ aoData);
                    $.ajax({
                        "dataType" : 'json',
                        "type" : "GET",
                        "url" : sSource,
                        "data" : aoData,
                        "success" : fnCallback
                    });
                }
```

is it possible to have something like,

```
success : function(){
    //.....code goes here
}
```

instead of "success" : fnCallback ------> which is last line of AJAX call.
In this function I would like to check a value send from server side.

Comment: It is possible. Have you already tried?

Comment: You are passing the argument to `FnServerData` as a callback to `$.ajax`. What would you like to use instead?

Comment: Thanks for you response Dvorak.

    function fnCallback(){
  alert("fnCallback");
 }    
I try to call this method. So I pass callback as argument into FnserverData. If it is not passed into FnServerData it keeps on processing without reporting any error.

Comment: I tried 
`success : function(){
    //.....code goes here
}` inside this function I gave alert. And I got the alert message properly. but datatable did not load

Comment: Then you have a different issue than how to do something on ajax success.

Comment: rajan.tsm:  I have the same issue... the ajax.success callback seems to keep the success to itself.  I've tried return true/false/data... no luck.  dont' know how to pass the data on to dataTable

Answer (score 79):

You can use dataSrc :

Here is a typical example of datatables.net

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
            "type" : "GET",
            "url" : "ajax.php",
            "dataSrc": function ( json ) {
                //Make your callback here.
                alert("Done!");
                return json.data;
            }       
    },
    "columns": [
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "office" },
            { "data": "extn" },
            { "data": "start_date" },
            { "data": "salary" }
        
        ]
    } );
```

Comment: it worked for me but not with return "json.data" only return "json", thanks

Answer (score 50):

You can use this:

```
"drawCallback": function(settings) {
   console.log(settings.json);
   //do whatever  
},
```

Comment: Perfect here using DataTables 1.10.10, Jquery 2.1.1.

Comment: Thanks a lot @AnasSafi I was struggling with this from yesterday. I tried to call additional javascripts on input fields in rows for calculations purpose and used `"initComplete"` but this did not worked but `"drawCallback"` saved my day.

Comment: This is the solution to the problem, especially if you use server-side processing for the dataTable draws.

Comment: Anyone who is facing issues, update your DataTables to the latest version and use "drawCallback" to make it work, simple life saving function. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks buddy. Previously I wrote a nasty piece code ( setting timeout to call a function :'D ) to call a function after ajax data-table load.  

This solution saved my day and I got rid of that nasty code. This is the best solution so far.

Comment: and how to distuingish between success and error? I tried normal function sucess and error but doesn;t work, any hints?

Answer (score 46):

The best way I have found is to use the [initComplete](https://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete) method as it fires after the data has been retrieved and renders the table. **NOTE** this only fires once though.

```
$("#tableOfData").DataTable({
        "pageLength": 50,
        "ajax":{
            url: someurl,
            dataType : "json",
            type: "post",
            "data": {data to be sent}
        },
        "initComplete":function( settings, json){
            console.log(json);
            // call your function here
        }
    });
```

Comment: yeah that worked i needed to aply datetime picker on textbox in jquery datatable, so i have to add this after all the rows are rendered on page,

Comment: Except if you refresh the table, the initComplete is never called again because it has already been initialized.

Comment: if you use dataTable.draw(), this function won't work. use dataSrc in ajax instead.

Comment: Imho this function requires the editor!
See:
Editor initialisation complete event. 
Please note - this property requires the Editor extension for DataTables.
https://editor.datatables.net/reference/event/initComplete

Comment: @Harm I have linked to the function documentation in the base version of Datatables in my answer. I do not use the editor extension. The answer by AnasSafi below seems to work better in some instances.

Answer (score 17):

This works fine for me. Another way don't work good

```
                'ajax': {
                    complete: function (data) {
                        console.log(data['responseJSON']);
                    },
                    'url': 'xxx.php',
                },
```

Comment: Interesting. I came here to get the syntax for 'success', but turns out that happens before the table is populated. 'Complete' worked perfectly.

Answer (score 6):

For datatables 1.10.12.

```
$('#table_id').dataTable({
  ajax: function (data, callback, settings) {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/your/url',
      type: 'POST',
      data: data,
      success:function(data){
        callback(data);
        // Do whatever you want.
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: For me, this stalls the process of populating the table.

Answer (score 3):

The success option of ajax should not be altered because DataTables uses it internally to execute the table draw when the data load is complete. The recommendation is used "dataSrc" to alter the received data.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [the docs](https://datatables.net/reference/event/xhr), `xhr` Ajax event would fire when an Ajax request is completed. So you can do something like this:

```
let data_table = $('#example-table').dataTable({
        ajax: "data.json"
    });

data_table.on('xhr.dt', function ( e, settings, json, xhr ) {
        // Do some staff here...
        $('#status').html( json.status );
    } )
```

Answer (score 2):

As per the question, I think the following should suffice:

```
 'ajax': {
              complete: function (data) {
               console.log(data['responseJSON']);
             },
                
            },
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's not exactly what you want to do, but using the ajax complete solved my problem of hiding a spinner when the ajax call returned.

So it would look something like this

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    "ajax": {
            "type" : "GET",
            "url" : "ajax.php",
            "dataSrc": "",
            "success": function () {
                alert("Done!");
            }       
    },
    "columns": [
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "office" },
            { "data": "extn" },
            { "data": "start_date" },
            { "data": "salary" }            
        ]
    } );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
             ajax: {
                url: "api/costing/",  // end point
                data:function (param) { // sending paramater to server
                    param.fk_style_id = data.id;
                },
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { // callback when error throwed
                    console.error('Error:', textStatus, errorThrown);
                },
                complete: function (data) { // callback when request completed
                    data = data.responseJSON;
                    console.log(data);
                },
            },
            columns: [
            ....
            ]
```

this method will work if you use success callback you may get some issues when loading data into columns

Answer (score -1):

Try Following Code.

```
       var oTable = $('#app-config').dataTable(
        {
            "bAutoWidth": false,                                                
            "bDestroy":true,
            "bProcessing" : true,
            "bServerSide" : true,
            "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
            "sAjaxSource" : url,                    
            "fnServerData" : function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
                alert("sSource"+ sSource);
                alert("aoData"+ aoData);
                $.ajax({
                    "dataType" : 'json',
                    "type" : "GET",
                    "url" : sSource,
                    "data" : aoData,
                    "success" : fnCallback
                }).success( function(){  alert("This Function will execute after data table loaded");   });
            }
```